# ExecuteQuery returns null while execute statement returns true

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Here's my java Code trying to fetch a ResultSet from DB.

```
    try{

        ps=conn.prepareStatement(QueryMapper.SCHEDULE_APPLICANT_STATUS);
        ps.setString(1,schedule_id);
        rs1=ps.execute();
        System.out.println(rs1);
        ResultSet rs = null;
        while(rs1)
        {
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(rs.next());
            Application applicationBean= new Application();
            System.out.println("ABC"+schedule_id);
            applicationBean.setScheduledProgramId(rs.getString(3)); 
            applicationBean.setStatus(rs.getString(2)); 
            applicationBean.setApplicantId(rs.getString(1)); 
            applicationList.add(applicationBean);
            applicationCount++;
        }

    }catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        log.error(sqlException.getMessage());
        System.out.println(sqlException.getMessage());
    }
```

When I try to run this, I'm not able to fetch the result set at rs using `executeQuery` statement. When I tried executing using `execute` statement it returned `true` which means some resultset is getting returned. Why is my `executeQuery` returning null.

The sql query I'm trying to run is

> SELECT * FROM APPLICATION WHERE SCHEDULED_PROGRAM_ID=?

This query runs fine and fetch results when executed in sql manager.

Can you tell where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `executeQuery` cannot return null. If it did, `rs.next()` would throw `NullPointerException`. See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--): *"Returns a `ResultSet` object that contains the data produced by the query; **never null**"*

Comment: If the query doesn't return any rows, perhaps `schedule_id` doesn't have the value you think it does. Just because `execute()` return true does't mean the result set isn't **empty**.

Comment: When I tried to run the query in SQL manager it fetched the required output.

Comment: What value did you replace `?` with when you ran it in SQL manager. Are you **absolute sure** that `schedule_id` has that value when you run the code?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and cross-checked many times and that was not wrong

Comment: Then are you *sure* you are connected to the **same database**? With the same user, i.e. connected to the **same schema**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code as shown, `rs` can only be `null` if `rs1` is false, which can only be the case if you are executing something that does not produce a result set (or if your JDBC driver has a bug, but that is less likely).

What you're doing though, makes no sense. If you use `execute()`, then you should not execute your query again to obtain the result set. Doing that is inefficient, as you're asking the database server to redo the work it did for your first `execute()`, use `getResultSet()` instead. As documented on [`PreparedStatement.execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()):

> The `execute` method returns a `boolean` to indicate the form of the
>   first result. You must call either the method `getResultSet` or
>   `getUpdateCount` to retrieve the result; you must call
>   `getMoreResults` to move to any subsequent result(s).

However, if you know you are executing a query that produces a result set (and a select **always** produces a result set, even if it is empty!), then you should use `executeQuery()`. That simplifies your code.

Your code also has an infinite loop. Did you mean to use `if (rs1)` instead of `while(rs1)`?

You should change your code to something like

```
try (PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(QueryMapper.SCHEDULE_APPLICANT_STATUS)) {
    ps.setString(1,schedule_id);
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        // or maybe if (rs.next())?
        while (rs.next()) { 
            Application applicationBean= new Application();
            System.out.println("ABC"+schedule_id);
            applicationBean.setScheduledProgramId(rs.getString(3)); 
            applicationBean.setStatus(rs.getString(2)); 
            applicationBean.setApplicantId(rs.getString(1)); 
            applicationList.add(applicationBean);
            applicationCount++;
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException sqlException) {
    log.error(sqlException.getMessage());
    System.out.println(sqlException.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This was what the initial code I did was. Even in the cases where there are results, resultset gets null and it doesn't enter into the while loop. So, I just did some modifications to check if it's returning true for execute statement and found out that it's returning true. When I run the query in SQL manager, I'm getting the result. Only problem is executequery doesn't return anything

Comment: @SrikarKrishna That is simply not possible unless you are using a very buggy JDBC driver, and I'm pretty sure that is not the case for Oracle drivers. An `executeQuery()` is only allowed to either return a result set, or throw an `SQLException` if something went wrong or if the query has no result set (eg it was an update instead of a select). You are probably ignoring an exception somewhere. Or do you mean that the result set is **empty**?

Comment: I did a commit and it's working fine now, I'm able to fetch the results.

Comment: @SrikarKrishna So, that actually means the problem was that the result was **empty**, not that it was `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two ResultSet objects and you only need to execute the PreparedStatement once. The typical pattern is:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // process the row returned by next()
    // e.g.,
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, But I was aware of that. As my resultSet.next() is always returning false, I just made some changes to see what execute statement returns. Now I came to know that it returns true even if it gets no rows in resultSet. Could you please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @SrikarKrishna If `resultSet.next()` always returns false, then no records were found matching the `WHERE` clause of the query. If you run the query directly in SQL Manager and it returns a rows, then **`schedule_id` does not have the value you think it does**, as I've [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670423/executequery-returns-null-while-execute-statement-returns-true?noredirect=1#comment92271596_52670423).

Comment: As answered by one of the contributor, I haven't commited the database. Maybe that was the reason. I should give it a try once.

Comment: @SrikarKrishna - You are correct. For a SELECT statement, `.execute` will always return `true` even if the statement returns no rows.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing your reader. 
It must be something like:  while(rs1.read())

Comment: Sorry, no. It sounds like you're thinking of C#.